# Canvas draws Bitmap smaller than orginal Picture

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, android-canvas

I actually work on an Game and need some backup because Canvas.

I draw a background with canvas. So i made Picture exactly for the resolution of the screen we work on. On the device the picture is to small and dont fitt to the screen. Did i miss something that the draw makes it smaller?

Here is some code

```
public class Map extends View{
int[][] mapArray = new int[32][18];
private Bitmap picture;
private Paint paint;

public Map(Context context){
    //basic init map
    super(context);

    this.setPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.newmap2));
}


public Bitmap getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(Bitmap background) {
    this.picture = background;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(picture, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Hope you can help me out
Best regards
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you put the bitmap in a high dpi directory (e.g. res/drawable-xhdpi) and your device is of a lower dpi ? In this case the image is scaled down on open.
What you are doing is not safe, other devices will have other screen sizes.

Comment: That could be possible. Its actually at hdpi with a resolution of 1280x800. 
Yea i know that it's not save but at this moment of the development we just develop for one device, so it should be fine without scaling

Comment: In this case pun it in res-drawable-nodpi and it will not scale

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks alot! Guess its the best at this point of development for us.

Comment: For accuracy.  The canvas is simply a placeholder for a collection of draw calls.  The actual drawing is to the bitmap that backs it.  The Canvas passed to you in the onDraw method will be the same size as your custom view.  The point is that with this knowledge, you could reasonably infer that the loading of 'picture' is the problem rather than wondering if onDraw() does something to scale - which it does not unless you pass a Matrix to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your device may have a significantly different DPI (pixel density), probably much higher, which would make it look like the image is much smaller than it should be. If you have a picture to show exactly how different they are, it may be easier to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This segments of code explain how to use the dimensions of the display to
determine the amount of down sampling that should occur when loading the image.
Hope that could help you

```
Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
int dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();
```